# Applying same filter for multiple mappings in restlet

Tags: java, servlet-filters, restlet

I have a restlet in which i am applying mapping for various resources all of which are supposed to pass through a common filter, but in case the filter condition is matched, i.e for return value "`CONTINUE`", all the filters redirect to different resources.

```
public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot()
{
   System.out.println("Called Application ");
   Router router = new Router();
   Filter fil1 = filterObj();
   router.attach("/helloworld",fil);
   fil.setNext(HelloWorldResource.class);
   router.attach("/hello",fil);
   fil.setNext(HelloWorldResource1.class);
   return router;
}
```

but what happens here is that at the end of execution, filter redirects to the last resource mentioned/used for `setNext()` , in this case `HelloWorldResource1`, i.e even if

```
http://localhost:8600/API/TRIAL/helloworld
```

is called, it redirects it to `HelloworldResource1.class` .

this problem is resolved if I create a different filter object for each mapping and use it for redirection, but i am not sure if it is the best way to do it. Can someone guide me to the most efficient and correct way to achieve the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing is chain-like in Restlet.  You need to build a chain with the filter, *then* the router.  Like this: filter->router->(resource1|resource2)

Using your example it would blook something like:

```
public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot()
{
 Router router = new Router();
 router.attach("/helloworld",HelloWorldResource.class);
 router.attach("/hello",HelloWorldResource1.class);
 Filter fil1 = filterObj();
 fil1.setNext(router);
 return fil1;
}
```

Note that a `Filter` is-a `Restlet` (it extends `Restlet`).  See http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.1/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Filter.html

Comment: if we follow the way you have suggested, the mapping will be already done for the routes and it won't pass through the filter, at least that's happening in my case. It is surpassing the condition in the filter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but my way does pass through the filter before hitting the restlets.  Perhaps the problem is your filter.

Comment: Can u please gimme a demo code for the filter ?? Now i doubt if i have written the filter correctly :/

Comment: I just added my filter code in the question, and i still can't understand what's wrong in it.. :(